# How to use Net_SSH2 on java maven?

Tags: java, ruby, maven

I want to run ruby using JAVA maven, but i don't know how to use it. If i run ruby inside php it's working :

```
$ssh = new \Net_SSH2($am->getIpClient());
if (!$ssh->login('nfc', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
//echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('killall -9 ruby');
$var1=$ssh->exec('./SCAS/daftarnfc.sh');
//echo "var = ". $var1;
if($var1 == null or $var1 == "" or empty($var1)){
    echo $ssh->exec('killall -9 ruby');
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to use Net_SSH2 on Java maven ?

It's possible to use Net_SSH2 on java maven ?